# how to make a cdf plot smoother and label y axis

Tags: r, ggplot2, ecdf

I read parameters "data1" and "data2" from files and use this code to plot cdf but I have two problems:

1. make the figure smoother
2. label Y axis to CDF

Please notice that this code is correct but I need some modifications.

```
df <- data.frame(x = c(data1, data2), ggg=factor(rep(1:2, c(19365,19365))))

ggplot(df, aes(x, colour = ggg)) + 
  stat_ecdf() + 
  labs(x='Time (ms)', ggg='CDF', fill='') + 
  theme_bw()+
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = 'grey'),
        panel.border = element_rect(colour = 'black'),
        axis.line = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank(),
        legend.direction='vertical',
        legend.position = c(1, 0.5),
        legend.justification = c(1, 0.5),
        legend.background = element_rect(colour = NA)) +
  scale_colour_hue(name='', labels=c('IEEE 802.11p','Our protocol'))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The empirical distribution function is always a step function and you should not smooth it in any way. Having said that, you can get the values for the empirical distribution function using `ecdf`. If you want to do any smoothing on the result (and this is not suggested), you can.

```
require(dplyr)
res <- df %>% 
  group_by(ggg) %>%
  do(data.frame(x = sort(.$x), 
                ecdf = ecdf(.$x)(sort(.$x))))
ggplot(res, aes(x, ecdf, colour = ggg)) + geom_step()
```

To relabel the `y` axis, you can use

```
labs(x='Time (ms)', y='CDF')
```